# How to get IP address of host when passed as extra-vars in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Say I am passing the hostnames to an Ansible playbook like so:

```
ansible-playbook ansible/db-playbook.yml --extra-vars "master=mydb-master, slave=mydb-slave"
```

In the playbook I want to access the actual ip address of the `mydb-slave` host:

```
- name: Copy ssh key to Slave
  command: ... "{{ mydb-slave }}"
```

In this case the output is the string literal `mydb-slave`, but I require the full `ip` address.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Anything that you do to convert a string literal (presumably hostname) to an IP is going to be either a DNS lookup or a search of your local /etc/hosts or something similar. Since your task name is labelled "copy ssh key to slave", why not just code up an ansible copy/rsync/whatever and let it resolve the IP normally?

Comment: What do you mean by "the full IP address"? What entity is supposed to resolve the name?

Comment: For context, in my `hosts` file  I have `[mydb-slave]123.456.78.91`. I want to pass in the `mydb-slave` var using the `--extra-vars` argument, but I don't want to hardcode the host in the playbook. Basically I just want to get the ip `123.456.78.91` from the `mydb-slave` var in the playbook.

Comment: In `[mydb-slave]123.456.78.91` hosts definition `mydb-slave` is a group and `123.456.78.91` is a host. So you try to do something wrong...

Comment: Can you not just specify hosts for that task?

Comment: Yes, in my playbook I have `- hosts: "{{ master }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the python module dnspython is installed on the host you are running ansible, then the following should work (if the hosts given are DNS names):

```
- name: Lookup slave IP
  set_fact: slave_ip="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ slave }}')}}"

- name: Copy ssh key to Slave
  command: ... "{{ slave_ip }}"
```

If the hosts are in your ansible inventory, the following should work:

```
- name: Copy ssh key to Slave
  command: ... "{{ hostvars[slave]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

Comment: Using this method the `{{ slave_ip }}` var is output as `NXDOMAIN`.

Comment: Where is this "full IP" recorded then? Ansible needs a source from which to learn.

Comment: The ip address for each group are in the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it should work with that scenario.